# stuff() not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query (simplified):

```
with temp1 as
(
select
table1.variable1
,table1.variable2
,table2.variable3

from table1

left join table2
on table1.variable1 = table2.variable1
)

select distinct
temp1.variable1
,temp2.variable2
,stuff((select ',' + table3.Description 
from table3 t3 where t3.variable1 = temp1.variable1 
for xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') AS 'Reason'
,table3.variable4
,table4.variable5


from temp1
left join table3 
on temp1.variable1 = table3.variabl3

left join table4
on temp1.variable1 = table4.variable4

order by variable1
```

the stuff()/for xml statement is replicating the "description" multiple times in the row, instead of consolidating each "description" into 1 row for each variable1.  So, I am getting this:

```
*Reason:*  
Variable1,Unit1||Excessive,Excessive,Excessive,Excessive   
Variable1,Unit1||Unusual ,Unusual,Unusual ,Unusual   
Variable1,Unit1||Under        ,Under        ,Under        ,Under  
Variable1,Unit1||Over                            ,Over                           ,Over                            ,Over   



Instead of:  
*Reason:*  
Variable1,Unit1||Excessive, Unusual, Under, Over
```

Someone asked this same question back in March, and no one answered.  Hoping to have better luck, as I have been working on this problem for 3 days now.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Um... You're stuffing `table3.Description` in your stuff statement, which is part of the outside statement... So it's no different to just concatenating table3.description with itself without a STUFF statement... What you should be doing is modifying your stuff to be something like `STUFF((SELECT ',' + [Description] FROM table3 AS T3 WHERE T3.variable1 = temp1.variable1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS Reason`. This way you're not selecting something outside the stuff statement, and you should get the result you want.

Comment: What about `stuff((select DISTINCT ','` ...

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour with a `STUFF` statement because you're selecting a column outside the stuff statement. The well-known `STUFF FOR XML PATH` trick only works when your sub-select isn't selecting columns from outside the `STUFF` statement.

This same behaviour could be observed with something as simple as the following:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (x INT, y CHAR(1));

INSERT @T1 VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'e'), (3, 'f');

SELECT DISTINCT T1.x, STUFF((SELECT ',' + T1.y FROM @T1 AS T2 WHERE T2.x = T1.x FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM @T1 AS T1;
```

The issue arises because you're using `STUFF` on something that's part of the outside query, which essentially just concatenates a column from your outside result set with itself (as many times as variable1 matches e.g. 4 matches will get the 4 concatenations you see. If you have, say, 6 matches on variable2 you'd get 6 concatenations from it).

For your issue, what you want to do is make sure you're not selecting outside columns, but still matching your where condition to an outside column. For example, I'd fix the above by altering it to:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (x INT, y CHAR(1));

INSERT @T1 VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'e'), (3, 'f');

SELECT DISTINCT T1.x, STUFF((SELECT ',' + T2.y FROM @T1 AS T2 WHERE T2.x = T1.x FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM @T1 AS T1;
```

The only difference being I'm selecting T2.y (from within the STUFF statement) instead of T1.y (from outside it).

So in your case, you'd modify the `STUFF` statement to look like this:

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + T3.[Description] FROM table3 AS T3 WHERE T3.variable1 = temp1.variable1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS Reason
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. But, I really am a novice at this. This is for my work. Hence, I can't disclose any real data. In trying to make everything "anonymous", I mistyped the stuff statement. How you demonstrated the stuff statement is actually how I did do it.  And it is still not "stuffing" all of my descriptions for each item into a single row.  When I test this statement in it's own query, setting up temp tables, it works exactly as it should.  But when I integrate into my real query, it won't work.  Although, it is essentially the same.  Any other suggestions?